# Finding the joint distribution of two dependent random variables given conditions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, bivariate-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

> Suppose $X \sim U(0,1)$ and $Y|X=x \sim U(0,1-x)$. Find the joint
>   distribution of $(X,Y)$ **given** that $X\le \frac{1}{2}$, $Y\le
>  \frac{1}{2}.$

My attempt:

The pdf of $X$ is $f_{X}(x) = 1$ for $x \in (0,1)$ and the pdf of $Y|X=x$ is $f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ for some $x\in (0,1)$ and $y\in (0,1-x)$.

Hence the (unconditional) joint density function should be $f_{XY}(x,y) = f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} $ where $x \in (0,1)$ and $y\in (0,1-x)$.

To find the distribution of $(X,Y)$ given the constraint let $A = \{(X,Y): \quad X\le \frac{1}{2} \cap Y\le \frac{1}{2} \}$.

Then, what I am trying to find is (using the CDF method) $$ \begin{align}\mathbb P (X\le x,Y\le y\vert (X,Y)\in A) &= \frac {\mathbb P\biggl(X\le x, Y\le y, X\le \frac 12, Y\le \frac {1}{2}\mathstrut \mathstrut \biggr) }{\mathbb P\Bigl(X\le \frac {1}{2},Y\le \frac 12\mathstrut \mathstrut \Bigr) }\mathstrut \\ &=   \frac {\mathbb P\Bigl(X\le \text{min}\Bigl(x, \frac {1}{2}\mathstrut \Bigr), Y\le \text{min}(y, \frac {1}{2})\Bigr) }{\mathbb P(X\le \frac 12, Y\le \frac 12\mathstrut \mathstrut ) }\mathstrut  \end{align} $$
at this point I'm not sure how to continue. For $(x,y) \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]^2$ the numerator becomes the (unconditional) CDF of just $(X,Y)$ but for e.g. $x > \frac{1}{2}$ and $y < \frac{1}{2}$ I'm not sure how to identify the distribution/simplify the expression.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
P(Y\le y, X\le x)&= \int_{-\infty }^x P\left(Y\le y\ |\,X=t\right)f_X(t)dt\\
&=\cases{\displaystyle  0& if $\ x\le0\ $or$\ y\le0$\\
\displaystyle\int_0^x\frac{y}{1-t}dt&if $\ 0<x\le1-y,y< 1$\\
\displaystyle\int_0^{1-y} \frac{y}{1-t}dt+\int_{1-y}^xdt&if $\ 0<y<1, 1-y<x<1$\\
\displaystyle\int_0^{1-y} \frac{y}{1-t}dt+\int_{1-y}^1dt&if $\ 1\le x, 0<y<1 $\\
\displaystyle\int_0^xdt&if $\ 0<x<1, 1\le y$\\
\displaystyle 1&if $\ 1\le x,y$
}\\
&=\cases{
\displaystyle  0&if $\ x\le0\ $or$\ y\le0$\\
-y\ln(1-x)& if $\ 0<x\le1-y,y< 1$\\
-y\ln(y)+ x+y-1 &if  $\ 0<y<1, 1-y<x<1$\\
-y\ln(y)+y&if $\ 1\le x, 0\le y<1$\\
x&if $\ 0<x<1, 1\le y$\\
1&if $\ 1\le x,y$}
\end{align}
Therefore $\ P\left(Y\le\frac{1}{2}, X\le\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\ln(2)}{2}\ $, and
\begin{align}
P\left(X\le x, Y\le y\left|\ Y\le\frac{1}{2}, X\le\frac{1}{2}\right.\right)&=\frac{P\left(X\le\min\left(x,\frac{1}{2}\right), Y\le\min\left(y,\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)}{P \left(Y\le\frac{1}{2}, X\le\frac{1}{2}\right)}\\
&=\cases{
0&if $\ x\le0\ $ or $\ y\le 0\ $\\
\displaystyle-\frac{2y\ln(1-x)}{\ln(2)}&if $\ 0<x,y\le\frac{1}{2}, $\\
2y&if $\ \frac{1}{2}<x, 0<y\le\frac{1}{2} $\\
\displaystyle-\frac{\ln(1-x)}{\ln(2)}&if $\ 0<x\le \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}<y $\\
1&if $\ \frac{1}{2}<x,y$
}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Does this figure describe the situation?

[image]

Comment: Yes, this being the (unconditional) joint density function

I'm not quite sure whether I understand why $\text{min}(x,\frac{1}{2}) = x $ and $\text{min}(y,\frac{1}{2}) = y $ however.

Comment: For instance, I could have $x = \frac{3}{4}$ and $y = \frac{1}{8}$ and the RHS would now longer be the (unconditional) CDF of $(X,Y)$ for the same value of $x$ and $y$. I would have

$$F_{XY\vert A}\Bigl(\frac {3}{4},\frac 18\mathstrut \mathstrut \Bigr)=\frac {F_{XY}\Bigl(\frac {1}{2},\frac 18\mathstrut \mathstrut \Bigr)}{\mathbb P(A) }\mathstrut $$

Comment: @user523384:  We don't have $\min (x, 1/2) = x$.  The diagonal boundary is for $y = 1-x$.  (I cut off the graph at $x = .9$ and $y = .9$ merely because the peak near at $x=1, y=0$ gets very large.

Comment: The final PDF of $(X,Y)|A$ is supposed to be $\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(A)} f_{XY} (x,y)$ for $(x,y) \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]^2 $. I having trouble seeing why that would be the case without $\text{min}(x,\frac{1}{2}) = x$